# Created multiple bundles with one command using npm and Browserify

Tags: npm, browserify

I am trying to make two bundle.js files, one for iOS and one for Android using a single build command.  I'd like to include a second app in the bundle but import as an alias and have Browserify determine the source.  I don't want to modify App.js but thought I could alias the appOne import and it would either import the blank string or an app.

This is what I have so far which bundles everything:

**Package.json**

...

```
 "scripts": {
    "build-dev": "NODE_ENV=production browserify appone-ios.js app.js > public/js/bundle-ios.js && cp public/js/bundle-ios.js public/js/bundle-ios.min.js | NODE_ENV=production browserify appone-andoird.js app.js > public/js/bundle-android.js && cp public/js/bundle-android.js public/js/bundle-android.min.js",
  },
```

...

**Appone-ios.js**

```
// default placeholder for import.
var appOne = '';
export default appOne;
```

**Appone-android.js**

```
// app for import.
var appOne = require('path/to/app/one');
export default appOne;
```

**App.js**

```
// Always import AppOne either a blank string or app so that app.js doesnt change.
var appOne = import('appOne');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to use Gulp.  This is complete aside from the 'watch' isn't working.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var transform = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

var ios = browserify({
   entries:['app.js']
 });

var android = browserify({
  entries:['app.js']
});

const bundle = () => {

  process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

  const bundleIOS = () => {
    ios.require('./app-ios.js', {expose:'app_alias'})
      .bundle()
      .pipe(transform('bundle-ios.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
      .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
      .pipe(rename('bundle-ios.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
      return ios;
  }

  const bundleAndroid = () => {
    android.require('./app-android.js', {expose:'app_alias'})
      .bundle()
      .pipe(transform('bundle-android.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'))
      .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
      .pipe(rename('bundle-android.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js'));
      return android;
  }

  return bundleIOS() && bundleAndroid();

}

const start = () => {
  return nodemon({
    script: 'server.js',
    watch: ['server.js', 'public/js/*', 'public/index.html', 'public/css/*'],
    ext: 'js html css',
    env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' },
  });
}

// Start local server and watch bundles.
gulp.task('start', start);

// Build minified versions for prod.
gulp.task('deploy', bundle);
```